# ButterKnife bind Fragments issue

Tags: android, butterknife

I have an issue with ButterKnife in Fragments.

For example, I have 2 fragments, the first fragment have a button in the middle on view. I bind it with:

```
unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
```

Then I implement `@BindView` and `@OnClick`:

```
@BindView(R.id.btnSignUp)
Button btnSignUp;

@OnClick(R.id.btnSignUp)
public void signUpClick() {
```

On SignUpClick current fragment replacing with new one:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setAllowOptimization(true);
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(fragment.getClass()));
transaction.commit();
```

The second fragment also included a button on top of the screen, with BindView implementation.

Issue is - if I tap in the middle of screen with empty area, signUpClick fired, not sure where is my mistake or it is ButterKnife mistake

Comment: how about popping the previous fragment with `transaction.popBackStack();`. Call it before add a new fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Its because fragments are placed in backstack. So if second fragment does not takes click action it is passed to first fragment.

You should probably add click listener on second fragment button also.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click listener to the second fragment's root with empty body. Assuming `R.id.root_fragment2` is the second fragment's root layout's id.

```
@OnClick(R.id.root_fragment2)
public void onRootClicked() {
}
```

Now the second fragment would consume the clicks and won't pass it to the fragment below.

Answer (score 0):

The second fragment is on the top of the screen , but when touch event is emitted ,if the second fragment not consume the event, the first fragment still could accept the touch event.
Fragment has a root view ,you could set the view like this: rootView.setClickable(true);